# NullPointerException on ArrayList in java

Tags: java

I am writing a simple java code but it gave me error of NullPointerException. My code is

```
String s="google";
ArrayList ss[]=new ArrayList[2];
ss[0].add(s);
System.out.println(ss[0]);
```

Comment: I see the error, but you should post the stack trace.  Also you should look up a null pointer exception and try to find it for your self: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

When you create the array, you do not create each element of the array. This will work:

```
ss[0] = new ArrayList();
ss[0].add(s);
```